# best approach check string null and empty C#

Tags: c#, string

which one is the best approach to check string null and empty?

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) or if(str != null && str != string.Empty)
```

or any much better approach?

Comment: First one with no doubt. Btw your question is subjective and off topic in Stakoverflow.

Comment: The first one is cleaner and easier to read by far.

Comment: uff ... http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,23a8597f842071f4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is much cleaner and easier to read. C# coders will be used to seeing it done that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) or 

if(str != null && str != string.Empty)
```

In general I prefer the first one, because it's easier to read, and because if you do

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(GetTextFromSomeFunction())) or 

if(GetTextFromSomeFunction() != null && GetTextFromSomeFunction() != string.Empty)
```

then the first one is clearly better, so for reasons of uniformity I use the first one.

Answer (score 1):

A string cannot be both null **and** empty. If it's null it's null, and if it's empty it's empty. So I think you mean to check if the string is null **or** empty.

Use `String.IsNullOrEmpty`, because it is equivalent to `result = s == null || s == String.Empty;`. [Here is the C# source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,23a8597f842071f4):

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(String value) {
    return (value == null || value.Length == 0);
}
```

You can also see the remarks here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: The OP code does not suggest a situation where a string is both null and empty, but rather that a string is both __not__ null and __not__ empty. The String `"test"` is _neither_ null _nor_ empty...